# Как сделать так, чтобы строчка скрипта(.sh) запускалась раз в какой то промежуток( например раз в 300 секунд)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, unix, sh

Вот есть у меня test.sh скрипт, и там есть строчка одна, так вот. Я хочу чтобы через 350 секунд например она запускалась заново, и так бесконечно, как так сделать?(linux, bash)

Comment: `while true; do строка скрипта; sleep 350; done`

Comment: Для игр со временем используйте `cron`

Answer (score 2):

Для одной строчки даже скрипт не обязателен.
`watch -tn 350 "Your_Script_String"`